# C-style macros in Go

Tags: macros, go

I've been playing with go for a week and something I miss from C is preprocessor macros.

What could I use to get this feature, besides hacking a build script that pipes go files through `clang -E` ?

Comment: I think you miss some of the philosophy of Go. For example the importance of clarity.

Comment: Of course clarity is important, but I don't think repeating multiple time the same code is better for clarity.

Comment: If you give an example of what you're trying to accomplish, it's likely there's a more "go" way to do it.

Comment: While not having macros, Go [supports "build flags and tags"](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#Compile_packages_and_dependencies) which can be used to [effect what's being built](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/).  This is not about metaprogramming, but it's one of the fields of application of macros in C, so I thought this worth mentioning.

Comment: The reason why Go did not introduce macros since the preprocessor would slow down the compiling. Maybe Google plan to use Go as a sort of scripts in future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, build flags are probably the best way to solve whatever you need. For example, if you wanted to have some features only available in development, use a `dev` flag:

File constants_dev.go:

```
// +build dev
const DEVELOPMENT = true
```

File constants_pro.go

```
// +build !dev
const DEVELOPMENT = false
```

Then in your code, just do a simple `if DEVELOPMENT { blah... }`. I find this much more readable than any preprocessor. This can get quite messy if you have a lot of build flags, but at that point you should probably be using command-line arguments instead.

In your comment, you mentioned duplication of code. If your code is really that repetitive, you should probably be putting it in a function anyway, or possibly restructure code to reuse the bits that are repetitive. Personally, I find that anything beyond simple boolean checks ends in hard to maintain code, especially with C-style macros.

It's the same thing with generics. In one Java library I've used, the class signature was something like this:

```
class Thing<A, B, C, D, E>
```

The library wasn't very well documented, so I had to read a significant amount of the code (both implementation and code that uses the library) to understand what was going on.

In Go, the language forces a style that generally leads to better, self-documenting code. I think the Go developers omitted things like a preprocessor and generics to avoid temptation to write hard to maintain, but clever, code.

I would advise you to try out the Go way before looking back on old idioms that you used before. I think you'll find that most of what macros and #defines were used for are largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

I think cpp, m4 or whatever may fulfill your desire to have Go preprocessed. If it's a good idea or not is a decision of yours, but be warned that any preprocessing is a substantial obstacle for adoption of any published Go code. (And for example, the build being dependent on makefiles is the same story.)